# Is this a correct declaration of an Array in Objective c?

Tags: objective-c

```
NSArray *arr=[[[NSArray alloc]autorelease]autorelease];
```

Answer (score 4):

Close, but no cigar.

If you want an autoreleased NSArray, you'd need to use:

```
NSArray *arr = [[NSArray alloc] init] autorelease];
```

That said, this will simply get you an empty immutable array, so you'll most likely want to populate it via one of the `initWithObjects:` style methods. (See the full [NSArray class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html) for more information.)

Answer (score 1):

Or you can just declare it like this:

```
[NSArray array];
```

This gives you an autoreleased instance of the array.